# How do I change a widget's markup?

Tags: 7, entities

I need to create another widget which acts exactly like a text field, but contains a button and link next to the element. How can I accomplish this?

I thought of two solutions.

- Copy the Text Module (with the Field Module) and look for the HTML
- Download the Autocomplete module and edit its markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7, to implement a new widget, you need to implement the following hooks:

- [hook_field_widget_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info/7)
- [hook_field_widget_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form/7)
- [hook_field_widget_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_error/7)

`hook_field_widget_info()` returns information about the type of widget implemented, such as the fields supported from the widget and for which the widget can be used. An example of implementation is [image_field_widget_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/image_field_widget_info/7).

```
function image_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'image_image' => array(
      'label' => t('Image'), 
      'field types' => array('image'), 
      'settings' => array(
        'progress_indicator' => 'throbber', 
        'preview_image_style' => 'thumbnail',
      ), 
      'behaviors' => array(
        'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_CUSTOM, 
        'default value' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_NONE,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

`hook_field_widget_form()` is the hook that returns the form field(s) necessary to get values for the field, which is what in Drupal 7 is called widget.
The reason you don't find any HTML in a module implementing a widget is that a widget is made of one or more form fields, which are defined using a form API array. If you look at [file_field_widget_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21file%21file.field.inc/function/file_field_widget_form/7), you will notice that it uses a [managed_file](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) form field, but it also uses a theme function, and a form field process function.

```
  $element_info = element_info('managed_file');
  $element += array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file', 
    '#upload_location' => file_field_widget_uri($field, $instance), 
    '#upload_validators' => file_field_widget_upload_validators($field, $instance), 
    '#value_callback' => 'file_field_widget_value', 
    '#process' => array_merge($element_info['#process'], array('file_field_widget_process')), 
    '#progress_indicator' => $instance['widget']['settings']['progress_indicator'],
    // Allows this field to return an array instead of a single value. 
    '#extended' => TRUE,
  );
```

```
  if ($field['cardinality'] == 1) {
    // Set the default value.
    $element['#default_value'] = !empty($items) ? $items[0] : $defaults;
    // If there's only one field, return it as delta 0.
    if (empty($element['#default_value']['fid'])) {
      $element['#description'] = theme('file_upload_help', array('description' => $element['#description'], 'upload_validators' => $element['#upload_validators']));
    }
    $elements = array($element);
  }
```

As I said, a widget is used to get the value associated with a field; when you need to show the value associated with a field, you need to create a formatter through [hook_field_formatter_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7). See [Field Formatter API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/group/field_formatter/7) for more information.